# How would I fill this dimensional array in C# with an for loop?

Tags: c#

I have an dimensional array which is hardcoded which i would like to make an for loop for so randomized characters get inserted.

And then show it in the console as 3 by 3 with an foreach (that is what i tried):

a b c 
d b a 
a b d

So i can count them since i need to make a pointing system as they have specific points. (this i can
manage on my own) But i was stuck with the dimensional array. It worked with a single dimension array but i need a 3 by 3 pointing game system.

```
Random random = new Random();
String chars = "ABCD";

// the array i want to make a for loop for
string[,] main = new string[3, 3];

// the example array how it should look after the for loop inserted data.
string[,] main_example = new string[3, 3] { { "c", "b", "a" }, { "d", "a", "b" }, { "a", "d", "a" } 
};

// inserts a or b or c or d.
for (int i = 0; i < cards9.Length; i++) {
    main[i, i] += chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
}

// the foreach to display the data in the console
foreach (string i in main) {
   System.Console.Write("{0} ", i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all very much, it actually worked like a charm :) I need to upgrade the code with console.color etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just use nested `for` loop, [`GetLowerBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlowerbound?view=net-5.0), and [`GetUpperBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=net-5.0):

```
var array = new string[3, 3];

for (var i = array.GetLowerBound(0); i <= array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (var j = array.GetLowerBound(1); j <= array.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        // replace guids to your initialization code
        array[i, j] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Single loop:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < cards9.Length; i++) {
        var c = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)].ToString();
        main[i / 3, i % 3] = c;
    }
```

The above code calculates all possible indexes of 3x3 array.

if print using below code then it will printout as follows

```
   for (var i = main.GetLowerBound(0); i <= main.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        for (var j = main.GetLowerBound(1); j <=main.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        {
            // replace guids to your initialization code
            Console.Write(main[i,j] + " ");
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine();
    }


B B D 
C C D 
A A C
```

You can check this fiddle -- https://dotnetfiddle.net/6vEu8f

Answer (score 1):

First issue is that you would liketo have lower case characters, but your `chars` contains only uppercase. Also, you want to have array of chars and we know that string is basically it, but more clear way would be to use `char[]`.

Second, it would simplify the code, if you could define number of rows and columns for your multidimensional array in one place and then use just parameters.

Third, to loop over mutlidimensional array, you need to use nested loop.

Putting it all together, I would suggest such changes to the code:

```
private static char[,] GenerateRandomCharArray()
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var chars = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    var charLength = chars.Length;
    var rows = 3;
    var columns = 3;
    var result = new char[rows, columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            result[i, j] = chars[rnd.Next(charLength)];
    
    return result;
}
```